# Best practice to create POJO / DTO for sending deep nested JSON

Tags: java, rest

When developing our API in spring boot that interacts with a third party API, I have to create a DTO to populate and send to a third party.  Thing is, the required JSON has a ton of nested objects.  For example:

```
{
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "firstname",
    "credentials": {
        "password" : {
          "hook": {
            "type": "default"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

So, what is simple to express in a JSON object is not simple to express in POJO/DTO classes, due to the high number of nested objects.

Should I create public or anonymous classes for all the nested properties? Or is there a better way to do this?

For example using anonymous, I can keep everything in one java file by not making the subobjects public.   What are your techniques for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

known problem... what I used often:

- wrap (hide) third party api in a module
- create custom pojo(s) containing only values needed from your domain logic
- use only this pojo(s) to interact between your domain/third party module
- create module private/inner classes mapping the third party api model as pojos
- or consider using nested maps instead with custom jackson de/serializers
- map domain pojo to api pojos

or, a bit hacky, if you only need to change same values

- store json request payload as a template with placeholders
- use e.g. regex to replace before send

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you suggested or simply de-serialize it into `Map<String, Object>` Using map makes it easy but you won't have content validation and modifying the content (if you need it becomes complex)